# Is it posible to get the position of point on an excel graph axis

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure this is possible but thought this was the best place to ask.

Is it posible to get the position of a series value on a graph in excel?

For example,  if I have a line graph in excel that has time along the x axis, is it possible to (using VBA) get the position of a specific point on that axis.

What I am trying to do is have a vertical line that is can be positioned based on a date entered by the user.

like this

[image]

Where the green line could be positioned by entering in a date (rather than just being manually moved)  (or also it could be set to automatically move to the current date etc).

I was then thinking that if the position is on the graph is queryable, then I can just access the line object and move it to any position I wanted through VBA.

Any Ideas?  or is this just not possible?

Comment: So you just need to have a green vertical line marking today?

Comment: that and being able to set a line to any user specified date. Like having a second line that could be used for milestones/release dates/ etc

Comment: Just wondering if you can somehow query the graph for the position of specified points on the x axis (in vba)

Comment: What do you mean by position? When you have a point it is already defined by its position x,y.

Comment: So for example in the attached picture, I would want to be able to enter into a cell, the date "20-04-15" and the green line would be repositioned to the 20-04-15 (from 17-04-15).

Comment: What kind of chart is this? An Excel chart? or simply an image that you downloaded to Excel? An Excel chart should have a corresponding data table either in the same worksheet or in an external one which you can reference for all data points

Comment: The graph is driven by the data in a worksheet (whether it came from a database or web query or whereever), so you already have the data defining each point. If you're asking about values between your data points along the curve, that's an interpolation based on your graph type. It's easy enough to position your green line anywhere... see Jon Peltier's [Add a Vertical Line to a Column or Line Chart](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineVertSeries.html). You'll see he defines a named cell `Today`. You can dynamically change your date line with that.

Answer (score 0):

The "cleanest" way to do this is to add the line to the chart as a new series.  In that way, Excel handles all of the positioning and your work is simplified.  To get a vertical line on a chart, there are a number of options.  I prefer this route:

1. Create a small 2x2 area with two dates and two values
2. Add in the date or x-axis value you want the line at (`E3` in image).  You can use `=TODAY()` here or some manually entered value.
3. Set the second x-axis value equal to the first
4. Use `MAX` and `MIN` on the data to get the values for each date.  You can also use 0 and 1 and a secondary axis, but I think `MAX/MIN` is easier.
5. Add the data to the chart and format as a marker with straight line.

**Formulas**

- `E3`: `=TODAY()`
- `E4`: `=E3`
- `F3`: `=MIN(C3:C27)`
- `F4`: `=MAX(C3:C27)`

**Result and chart data series for vertical line**

[image: results and chart]